# UTF-8 Encoding a string with double Quotes in C# 

Tags: c#, encoding, utf8-decode

```
StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();
request.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");

byte[] msg;
string decoded;

msg=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request.ToString());
decoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg);
```

decoded  is `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>`

the result has `\"`
My question is how can I encode the message with quotes and still get string without `\"` after decdoing
If I use AppendLine that the result also has `\r\n`

Comment: Where are you looking at the result? In Visual Studio Debug mode? If this is the case rest assured => there are no `\"` in the actual string. It's the debugger representation of strings. This being said, using a StringBuilder to manipulate XML is probably one of the worst things you could do. XML should be manipulated only with XML parsers.

Comment: Thanks and Yes I was looking in the debugger, As this is just a single message I will send I wasnt XML parser..But I will have look into it thanks

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking at the string in the debugger? If so it will show the string as if it were a string literal in C#. The `\` are not really there. You can esily verify that if you output the string somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

@joey's answer is the correct one - but since XML supports single quotes you can use this instead - which I find cleaner to read:

```
request.Append("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'"?>");
```

Comment: request.Append(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"); 
same result
request.Append(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'"?>"); 
if I do AppendLine I still see /r/n in debugger.